# The extern class specifier

Tags: c

If I have an external variable like this:

```
int a;
```

is right that declaration is equals to:

```
extern int a = 0;
```

and not equals to:

```
extern int;
```

Is it the same as local variable where write something like this:

```
int local;
```

is equals to:

```
auto int local;
```

In both cases does the compiler put, as default, the specifier `extern` or `auto`?

Comment: A variable declared at global scope is `extern` by default; is that what you're asking?

Comment: When extern is used with a variable, it’s only declared not defined.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, yes but also if it's equals to extern int a;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules for linkage and external definitions are a little odd, partly for historic reasons (cf. for example [this](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/c1.html#3-1-2-2) C89 rationale). The rules for objects (they are different for function declarations) are:

**At file scope:**

- `auto` and `register` are not allowed, a diagnostic is required<sup>1)</sup>.
- `static` means internal linkage<sup>2)</sup> and the declaration is a (tentative) definition<sup>3)</sup>.
- `extern` means linkage as already declared, if none is declared, external linkage<sup>4)</sup>.
- No storage-class specifier means external linkage<sup>5)</sup> and the declaration is a (tentative) definition<sup>6)</sup>.
- If multiple declarations disagree on linkage, the behaviour is undefined<sup>7)</sup> (Gcc aborts compilation, as do most compilers, I guess).

A tentative definition means, the object will be defined in the same translation unit, if there is no explicit definition, `0` is assumed.<sup>8)</sup> Multiple explicit definition are a constraint violation for identifiers with internal linkage; for identifiers with external linkage, the behaviour is undefined (Gcc aborts compilation).<sup>9)</sup>

The first two examples are mostly, but not exactly equivalent.

```
int a;
```

`a` has external linkage. The declaration is a tentative definition; if no explicit initialization follows, it is initialized to 0. If there was another declaration `static int a;`, the behaviour would be undefined.

```
extern int a = 0;
```

This, on the other hand, declares `a` to have external linkage only if either an external declaration is already visible or none is visible. If this was followed by a static declaration of `a`, the behaviour was undefined; if this was preceeded by one, the linkage would be internal. This declaration also initializes `a` to 0, no other explicit definition is allowed to appear in the translation unit.

```
extern int a;
```

(I assumed `extern int a;` instead of `extern int;`. If you really meant the latter: That’s a constraint violation.)

This is an (external, if no other declaration is visible) declaration without definition. Usually, the definition appears in another translation unit. It must appear somewhere if the identifier is used in an expression where it is evaluated.

**At block scope:**

- `extern` means the same as at file scope, except there is no tentative definition. No initialization is allowed.<sup>10)</sup>
- `static` means no linkage (but static storage-duration).<sup>11)</sup> If there is no initialization, it is initialized to 0 (once, at program startup).<sup>12)</sup>
- `auto` or none means no linkage. If there is no initialization<sup>13)</sup>, the value of the variable is indeterminate, reading such a value is undefined (not exactly, but practically).
- `register` is the same like `auto`, but it’s a constraint violation to take its address.
- No re-declaration is allowed for identifiers (denoting an object) with no linkage.<sup>14)</sup>

Thus, the last two examples are equivalent.

The two storage-class specifiers not mentioned here are `typedef` and (since C11) `_Thread_local`.<sup>15)</sup>

References to C11 (n1570):

<sup>1)</sup> 6.9 p2. <sup>2)</sup> 6.2.2 p3. <sup>3)</sup> 6.9.2 p2. <sup>4)</sup> 6.2.2 p4. <sup>5)</sup> 6.2.2 p5. <sup>6)</sup> 6.9.2 p2. <sup>7)</sup> 6.2.2 p7 <sup>8)</sup> 6.9.2 p2. <sup>9)</sup> 6.9 p3 and p5. <sup>10)</sup> 6.2.2 p4 and 6.7.9 p5. <sup>11)</sup> 6.2.2 p6. <sup>12)</sup> and <sup>13)</sup> 6.7.9 p10. 14) 6.7 p3. 15) cf. 6.7.1.

Comment: So int a; and extern int a = 0; are not equals? Are "almost" equals?

Comment: If that's the only file-scope declaration of `a` in the translation unit, they are equal; and they are equal for every sane use (making use of those peculiarities I described here is mostly considered bad). `static int a; extern int a = 0;` is valid, for example (`a` has internal linkage and is initialized to 0), but `static int a; int a;` isn't (`a` has both internal and external linkage). `int a; int a = 14;` would be valid (`a` has external linkage and is initialized to 14), but `extern int a= 0; int a = 14;` is invalid (multiple non-tentative definitions) etc.

Comment: Please, still one point: If I had written: int a = 100 or extern int a = 100; were in this case both equals? P.S. I wrote that declaration not in the same time...

Comment: Still the same, `extern` may follow a `static` declaration, but if no storage-class specifier is given (implying external linkage), then this conflicts with a prior static declaration. `int a = 100;` differs from `int a;` in that the former has an explicit, the latter a tentative definition. A tentative definition may be followed by an explicit one, an explicit one may not. Further, `int a = 100;` is the commonly used style and Gcc gives a warning for `extern int a = 100;`.

Comment: @mafso: That's a really good in-depth explanation of the rules, but I wonder, is there any practical merit to doing these double definitions/declarations, or we can simply regard it as a historical artefact?

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev: Probably mostly historical, I guess, and to allow some variation (see the linked rationale). Somewhat related: C11's (informative) Annex J lists as common extensions (from n1570) J.5.4 _A function identifier, or the identifier of an object the declaration of which contains the keyword `extern`, has file scope (6.2.1)._ and J.5.11 _There may be more than one external definition for the identifier of an object, with or without the explicit use of the keyword `extern`; if the definitions disagree, or more than one is initialized, the behavior is undefined (6.9.2)._

Answer (score 4):

`extern int a` at the file scope *declares* a variable but does not *define* it. Such a declaration basically says that the variable is to be found in another compilation unit and it is the job of the linker to resolve its address when merging the individual object files. Omitting the `extern` in that case will *define* the variable in the current unit and have its initial value set to `0` (a tentative definition). Such a defined variable will have external linkage (no matter that `extern` is omitted), unless `static` is used.

`extern int a = 0` is a *definition* and the `extern` is pointless because you are telling the compiler to initialise the variable here. In that case `extern` can be safely omitted.

Is it the same as `auto`? To the extent that both `extern` and `auto` are storage class specifiers, yes. However, automatic variables (whether or not defined with that keyword) are not initialised implicitly. Working with an uninitialised `auto` variable is undefined behaviour. Also, it is not possible to *declare* a variable within a function, so there is a lot less confusion here.

Answer (score 2):

**Instantiate the global variable in this file:**

```
int a;     // instantiation
int a = 0; // instantiation and initialization
```

The address of the global variable will be resolved during compilation.

---

**Tell the compiler that the global variable is instantiated in another file:**

```
extern int a;
```

The address of the global variable will be resolved during linkage.

---

With `extern int a = 0`, you are forcing the instantiation of `a`, thus making `extern` useless.

Comment: (1) is called a "tentative definition", (2) definition with intitialization, (3) external declaration, (4) would be such a declaration with initialization, which is an error.

Comment: @JensGustedt: I intuitively thought the same about 4, but understanding `extern`, I've never really tried it. I did now, and it seems to work (making the `extern` essentially useless).

Answer (score 0):

int a; and extern int a=0; are equal. when we initialize a extern variable the memory is also allocated for that variable ie definition also occurs which is similar to int a;. 
Refer http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c for more info on extern.